# Kotlin Multiplatform fails gradle task cinteropAFNetworkingIos

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I am writing a little kotlin multiplatform app (android and iOS) and wanted to use in the shared code a native iOS library. I use the [official native cocoa pods plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html) and followed the setup there:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
   ...
    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        frameworkName = "sharedClient"
        podfile = project.file("../iosClient/Podfile")

        pod("AFNetworking") {
            version = "~> 4.0.1"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run gradle to build the app the task `cinteropAFNetworkingIos` fails:

```
> Task :sharedClient:cinteropAFNetworkingIos Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/n9/5pkml05d7mn3xzdyty8cx5380000gn/T/3707914287112298431.m:1:9: fatal error: could not build module 'AFNetworking'
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:192)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:68)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:531)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:268)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:60)

> Task :sharedClient:cinteropAFNetworkingIos FAILED
```

I think it is more of a cocoa pods issue on my local machine, but I don't really know how cocoa pods works exactly under the hood. I think cocoa pods did not download AFNetworking.

In a plain iOS / xcode project (not kotlin multiplatform app) I have used successfully cocoa pods, so I think it is fair to assume the required cocoa pods gems are installed on my machine.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin 1.5.31 and have Xcode 13 installed, the problem might be caused by these versions' compatibility issue. The details can be found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48807).

In general, the problem was caused by the new `NSAttributeString` support in Xcode. This type requires a macro attribute which Kotlin/Native 1.5.31 was unable to process. Therefore, Kotlin's cinterop tool was unable to build `AFNetworking` and to create bindings for its API.

To deal with this problem, Kotlin team recommends using [the following workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48807#focus=Comments-27-5210791.0-0). Add these lines into the Gradle script where you declare this cocoapods dependency.

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CInteropProcess::class.java) {
    settings.compilerOpts("-DNS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(A)=")
}
```